# Google Sheets : How can I sum two calculated fields in a pivot table

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

Inside a pivot table, I want to store in the Baz column the sum of Foo and Bar column. How can I reference the B and C columns so **Baz = Foo + Bar** ? I tried to :

1. Reference the columns by theirs names : Does not work
2. Reference the columns by theirs ranks : Work only if I stick to a cell : B2+C2 will kinda work but B+C wont.

The example is available here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v_D2e-yXpG7PlghGCiYjU0Tfw6ct2_Uaq4npQ1LkEKE/edit?usp=sharing

[image: example pivot table1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this in the `calculated field` part of the pivot (as in screenshot)

```
=sum('number of units')+average('price per unit')
```

[image]

Comment: Not as I had think it would work, but it does the job in the end.